# How can I incorporate PDO using this coding set up to allow punctuation such as '/" in the fname=$name, $desc, & city column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to place PDO into my code, but I do not know where to place the coding that will allow me to do that. I want the post in the name field to be able to entered as "mike's", but the current setup does not allow this. I need PDO, and I can't seem to find where exactly I should place the code.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST["element_1"];
    $stdatemm = $_POST["element_2_1"];
    $stdatedd = $_POST["element_2_2"];
    $stdateyy = $_POST["element_2_3"];
    $endatemm = $_POST["element_3_1"];
    $endatedd = $_POST["element_3_2"];
    $endateyy = $_POST["element_3_3"];
    $staddr = $_POST["element_4_1"];
    $addr2 = $_POST["element_4_2"];
    $city = $_POST["element_4_3"];
    $state = $_POST["element_4_4"];
    $zip = $_POST["element_4_5"];
    $desc = $_POST["element_5"];
//$file=$_FILES['element_6'];
    $link = $_POST["element_7"];
    $stdate = $stdatemm . "-" . $stdatedd . "-" . $stdateyy;
    $endate = $endatemm . "-" . $endatedd . "-" . $endateyy;
    $user = $_POST["postuser"];
    if (($_FILES['element_6']['size']) > '0') {

        $fileName = $_FILES['element_6']['name'];
        $tmpName = $_FILES['element_6']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['element_6']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['element_6']['type'];

        if ($fileName != "") {
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmpName, '../login/image/' . $fileName)) {//image is a folder in which you will save image
                if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

//$fileName = addslashes($fileName);
                }
                $query = "INSERT INTO   test2($name,stdate,endate,addr1,addr2,city,state,zip,name,size,type,content,link,description,user)VALUES('$name','$stdate','$endate','$staddr','$addr2','$city','$state','$zip','$fileName','$fileSize','$fileType','$content','$_POST[element_7]','$desc','$user')";
            }
        }
    }
    else
        $query = "INSERT INTO test2($name,stdate,endate,addr1,addr2,city,state,zip,name,size,type,content,link,description,user)VALUES('$name','$stdate','$endate','$staddr','$addr2','$city','$state','$zip',' ','0',' ',' ','$_POST[element_7]','$desc','$user')";

    $q2 = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed' . mysql_error());
    if ($q2) {
        echo "Active";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test2 ORDER BY stdate DESC");
$data = mysql_query("SELECT stdate FROM test2 ORDER BY id ASC");
$y = 1;
echo "<div style='min-height:500px;margin-top: 10px;'><table style='-moz-border-radius:  15px;border-radius: 15px;border-bottom:1px solid gray;background-color:white;margin:  auto;width: 75%;'><tr style='font-weight:bold;'><td></td><td>Title</td><td>Date</td> <td>City</td></tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td><img src='../login/image/" . $row['name'] . "'  style='width: 125px;height: 94px;'></td>";
    echo "<td><form action='deals.php' method='post' style='margin:0px;'><input type='hidden' value='" . $row['fname'] . "' name='name'><input type='submit' style='background-color: white;
border: none;color: #FF0000;text-decoration: underline;' name='submit2'     value='" . $row['fname'] . "'></form><br/>";
    echo "</td><td>" . $row['stdate'] . "</td>";
    echo "</td><td>" . $row['city'] . "</td></tr>";
    $y++;
}
echo "</table></div>";
include("../login/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: Your code can't have worked; most of your variables are incorrect (`$=$_POST["element_2_1"];` isn't a valid assignment). Are you sure you posted the correct code? Or had you self-obfuscated your code?

Comment: @ChrisForrence I deleted information so it wouldn't be shown

Comment: @user2512412 you deleted the name of the vars? really? Just deleting usernames and passwords is enough. And in this case there was not even the needed.

Comment: @user2512412 - I can dig obfuscating code. I can't dig non-working code because of the obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use a PDO wrapper. [This](https://gist.github.com/chrisforrence/6255518) is an example of one that I've written before (and you can use it if you'd like, assuming you can use GPL). In normal usage, you'd include the file, then instantiate an instance of it.

```
$dbi = DBConnection::getInstance();
$username = sanitize($_GET['username']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username=?";
$args = array($username);
$users = $dbi->execute($query, $args);
if($users['count'] > 0)
{
    foreach($users['result'] as $row)
    {
        echo $row['username'] . '<br />';
    }
}
$dbi = null;
```

An example of what one of your queries might look like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO test2(name, stdate, endate, addr1, addr2, city, state, "
             . "zip, name, size, type, content, link, description, user)"
             . " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$args = array($name, $stdate, $endate, $staddr, $addr2, $city, $state,
                $zip, $fileName, $fileSize, $fileType, $content, 
                $_POST['element_7'], $desc, $user);
try {
    $dbi = DBConnection::getInstance();
    $dbi->execute($query, $args);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}
$dbi = null;
```

Comment: In a separate file, then using `require_once('DBConnection.php');` at the top of the files that you'd be using the PDO wrapper.